# Retornar resultado fetch js em uma variavel global

Tags: javascript, ajax, fetch

Olá, desculpem a pergunta de leigo.

Basicamente quero usar o retorno do fetch e colocar numa variável, que eu possa utiliza-lo em outras funções para fazer 1 requisição somente, hoje estou usando  `const xhr = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
        xhr.open('GET', 'URL', true);`

porém seguindo essa estrutura abaixo (alguém me informa o nome pra estudar).

```
    let info = '';

    // Não sei o nome exato dessa estrutura de funções, ja pesquisei mas não achei
    // Eu vi assim uma vez e pra mim fica bonito e organizado rs

    const product = {
        //let info = ''; **Não sei como definir variável aqui dentro**

        getJson: function(){
            fetch('urlToFetch')
            .then(response => response.json()) 
            .then(result => {console.log(result)})
            .catch(err => {console.error('Failed retrieving information', err)})
        info = result
        return info
        },

        listJson: function(){
            // Quero usar as infos da variável 'info' aqui
        },

        changeJson: function(){
            // Quero usar as infos da variável 'info' aqui 
        },

        init: function(){
            product.getProduct()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Quando vais usar `listJson`? ou seja, podes mostrar o código ou a lógica que a tua aplicação tem? Esses métodos que precisam de `info` são chamados como?

Comment: O listJson é basicamente escrever o resultado no dom.

Comment: Se mostrares o código todo posso dar uma resposta. Sem mais código não consigo responder...

Comment: Eu só quero usar o retorno do fetch numa variável global, as outras funções que coloquei são somente de exemplo...

Comment: Então coloca o `info = result` dentro do `.then(` e o retorno do fetch vai estar disponível nessa variável global... o problema (e que acho que é o que queres resolver) é que outras funções correm a contar que esse `info` tem o valor do `fetch` mas no inicio ainda não tem... certo?

Answer (score -1):

A variavel products é um objeto de javascript. Objeto de javascript contem apenas chave e valor.

```
const products = {
  chave1: 'valor1',
  chave2: 'valor2'
}
```

No caso, o valor das chaves podem ser string number ou objetos mais complexos como função por exemplo:

```
const products = {
  chave1: function () {
            return 'valor1';
          },
  chave2: function () {
            return 'valor2';
          },
}
```

Mas como a const products é um objeto ela aceita apenas chave e valor. Não é possivel declarar variavel diretamente no objeto como vc fez.

```
const products = {
  let variavel = ''; // ERRADO
  chave1: function () {
            return 'valor1';
          },
  chave2: function () {
            return 'valor2';
          },
}
```

Você pode declarar uma outra chave para ser usada como variavel caso seja esta sua intenção

```
const products = {
  variavel: '', // CERTO
  chave1: function () {
            return 'valor1';
          },
  chave2: function () {
            return 'valor2';
          },
}
```

Porém dentro das chaves de função tem livre uso de variavel

```
const products = {
  variavel: '', // CERTO
  chave1: function () {
            const valor = 'valor1'; // CORRETO
            return valor1;
          },
  chave2: function () {
            return 'valor2';
          },
}
```